# Controller 'new' method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I am following [a tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-controllers.htm)
and I am getting an error for my `new` action.  I am using the tutorial as a guideline and my database differs.  Here is my code:

```
def new
  @skill = Skill.new
  @skills = Skill.find(:all)
end
```

and here is my error message:

```
uninitialized constant SkillsController::Skill
```

@skill = Skill.new is the highlighted line so my mistake should be there somewhere.  Thank you and I will keep trying to fix it with the power of research!

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^solved^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Now I am getting a new error and it seems my database is not quite built right for the skill id's. I am trying to go to localhost:3000/skills/list,  Here is my code:

```
    class SkillsController < ApplicationController
  def list
    @skills = Skill.find(:all)
   end

   def show
    @skills = Skill.find(params[:id])
   end
```

and my error is:

Couldn't find Skill without an ID

and it highlights:

```
@skills = Skill.find(params[:id])
```

as the problem area.  Thank you for anyone who knows how to solve this issue and also, If I should re-post as a different question let me know and I will do so.  Thanks again and huzzah for the web dev community!

Comment: Do you have a class named `Skill`?

Comment: seems you don't have model named `skill`

Comment: Either that, or you have a syntax error in the skill.rb file. In rails console you can try `> Skill`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Syntax**

Firstly, [`Rails 4` syntax](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches) should read as:

```
def new
    @skills = Skill.all
end
```

--

**Error**

In regards to your error, as described in the comments, you really need to ensure you have the `Skill` class available in your application.

You must remember Rails is basically just a series of classes & modules, which means that if you're trying to call a "model", you're essentially calling a [Ruby Class](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/tut_classes.html) which needs to be loaded (as constants).

The problem is your application hasn't got the `Skill` class (model) loaded. This is most likely the result of not having it in your `app/models` directory:

```
#app/models/skill.rb
Class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
   ... 
end
```

What concerns me, though, is how your error is trying to wrap this model in another class - `SkillsController`. This would typically be the case if you've [namespaced](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) the controller; but either way you should create the `model`, restart your server & test again

Comment: Thank you, I fixed my controller in regards to the pluralized namespace.  I am however getting a new error and I have tried a few things but to no prevail.  Thanks a lot Rich and I hope you may have further insight for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are messing up with rails conventions. Rails expect *Controller class names* to be **pluralized**, such that `SkillsController` would be the controller class for the *skills table*.  Rails will then look for the class definition in a file called `skills_controller.rb` in the /app/controllers directory. For more information on naming conventions refer [here](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7).

Also since your error says `uninitialized constant SkillsController::Skill`. I think you don't have your **skills table setup with Skill.rb model** notice your *table name will be plural and your model name will be singular*

Comment: Thank you that cleared up that error.  I am getting another error though and I will post above.

Comment: I think a new question would have been nice anyways you are getting this error in skills/list page? And you should change "Skill.find(:all)" with "Skill.all" in your list method

Comment: Thank you, I think I will re-post to make things less complicated.  I changed my list action to Skill.all but it did nothing for the show action error.